# D3 Non-Continuous Dates Domain Gives Gaps on X-Axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to plot some time series data that is not continuous (gaps in the dates for weekends, holidays, etc..). It's daily data.

The data looks something like:

```
date,value
1/2/15,109.33
1/5/15,106.25
1/6/15,106.26
1/7/15,107.75
1/8/15,111.89
1/9/15,112.01
1/12/15,109.25
1/13/15,110.22
...
```

So I define my `x` and `y` `scales`:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
```

And set the domain from my source data:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }));
```

The problem however, is that my dates have gaps in them. And my x-axis now includes those missing dates (`d3.time.scale()` does this automatically I guess because it maps to a continuous range?).

`.extent()` finds the max and min values in `date` then `.domain()` returns those max and min values as the range for the x-axis.  But im not sure how to handle gaps and return the non gap dates to the range.

So my question is:  How can I have my x-axis range only include the dates that are in my data set? And not "fill in the blanks".  Should I play with the `d3.time.scale().range()` ? or do I need to use a different `scale`?

What is the correct way to do this? Can someone please point me in the right direction or give some example?  Thank you!

Also please, I want to solve with with just plain d3 and javascript.  I am not interested in using any 3rd party abstraction libraries.

Comment: You could use an ordinal scale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Lars Kotthof points out, you can create an ordinal x axis, which "looks" like a time scale.
Assuming you want to plot your time series as a line, here is an example how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ee2todev/3Lu46oqg/

If you want to customize your format for the dates, e.g. respresent the date as day (of the week), day and month you have to convert your string to a date first.
I added one example which formats the dates in a common German format. But you can easily adjust the code to your needs.
http://jsfiddle.net/ee2todev/phLbk0hf/

Last, but not least, you can use

```
axis.tickValues([values])
```

to choose the dates you want to display. See also:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat

Answer (score 1):

The [d3fc-discontinuous-scale](https://d3fc.io/api/discontinuous-scale-api.html) component adapts any other scale (for example a d3 time scale) and adding the concept of discontinuities.

These discontinuities are determined via a 'discontinuity provider' the built in `discontinuitySkipWeekends` allows you to skip weekends.

Here's an example:

```
const skipWeekendScale = fc.scaleDiscontinuous(d3.scaleTime())
  .discontinuityProvider(fc.discontinuitySkipWeekends());
```

And here's a complete demo: https://bl.ocks.org/ColinEberhardt/0a5cc7ca6c256dcd6ef1e2e7ffa468d4