# White space between values of a line graph

Tags: csv, d3.js, graph, data-visualization, fill

I've created a line graph where the area under the graph is filled based on the rank of the values from data, but there is white space between data point assignments. I'm using `d3.nest()` to create sub dataGroups. Is there a better way to go about this that will eliminate the white space?

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tx4J60fGzSl658y4hGMU?p=preview).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}

text.shadow {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    stroke-opacity: 0.7;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
          stroke-width: 0;
}

.area {
    stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// function for the x grid lines
function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5)
}

// function for the y grid lines
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
}

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    var dataGroup = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
            return d.rank;
        })
        .entries(data);

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i){
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(d.values)
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("d", area);
        });

    svg.selectAll(".area")
        .style("fill",function() {
          return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)";
        })

    // Draw the x Grid lines
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    // Draw the y Grid lines
    svg.append("g")            
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Add the text label for the X axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                             (height+margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Distance");

    // Add the text label for the Y axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("x", margin.top - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("");

    // Add the title
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))     
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "16px")
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")
        .text("Elevation Graph");

});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Isn't the reason that your data does not cover every day? You might look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/28131145/3902128

Comment: Yes. That is the reason, but I'm looking for a way to include the interpolated line values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest is insufficient for this. The problem with nest is that each data point (i.e. each day) belongs to only one subgroup (i.e. element of `dataGroup`). However, rendering it requires the first day of each group to also be the last day of the preceding group. So you need to get more sophisticated with how you generate `dataGroup`. At first I was going to suggest using a somewhat elaborate loop in place of `.nest()` (which you can still try to figure out how to do, if you'd like). However, I realized that you can still use nest just like you have it and then do a simple pass through the resulting groups and append the first element of each group to the group before it:

```
dataGroup.forEach(function(group, i) {
  if(i < dataGroup.length - 1) {
    group.values.push(dataGroup[i+1].values[0])
  }
})
```

Here's the [updated example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7dFzhtdfKe3N5wuZVq9?p=preview).