# Logarithmic time scale

Tags: d3.js

How to make a logarithmic datetime scale in D3?

a simple time scale is like this:

```
d3.time.scale()
.domain([new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date()])
.range([0, 500])
```

and a simple log scale is like:

```
d3.scale.log()
.domain([new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date()])
.rangeRound([0, 500])
.base(10)
```

Tried to chain their syntax in a various ways with no effect.

Chart will position users by last login date. Range will be about one year. If we space data linearly, most users will collide during last days/hours. With logarithm we can zoom last hours.

Solution could be by interactive zoom or several charts. But goal here is to make single static chart with nonlinear overview of year.

One alternative could be to convert datetime to "days from now", a number. It would work for data. But then I wouldn't know how to label axis ticks like "01-01-2014"...

Comment: I suppose you have to customize the time scale by hand. See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129412/d3-non-continuous-dates-domain-gives-gaps-on-x-axis) for customizing time scale to non continuous dates.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below seems to fool d3js into thinking it has a real scale object.  It should make a good starting point:

```
var xt = d3.scaleUtc()
    .domain([start, now])
    .range([1, width])
var xp = d3.scalePow()
    .exponent(2)
    .domain([1, width])
    .range([0, width])

// Fool d3js into thinking that it is looking at a scale object.
function x_copy() {
    var x = function(t) { return xp(xt(t)) }
    x.domain = xt.domain
    x.range = xp.range
    x.copy = x_copy
    x.tickFormat = xt.tickFormat
    x.ticks = xt.ticks
    return x
}
x = x_copy()

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two scales and use one after the other. First use the time scale and than the log or pow scale.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0,width]);

var xLog = d3.scale.pow().exponent(4)
    .domain([1,width])
    .range([0,width]);
```

than I'm using .forEach to get the linear points:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseDate(d.start); }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.start = x(parseDate(d.start));
  });
```

when I'm drawing the objects I add the log scale:

```
.attr('cx', function (d) { return xLog(d.start)})
```