# Create D3 interval excluding weekends

Tags: d3.js

I want to create an interval for axis in D3 (that doesn't have start or end limit), but I would like to exclude weekends, is it possible?

This is what I have:

```
 x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x_time_scale)
            .ticks(d3.time.monday, 1)
            .tickFormat(function (d) {
                return moment(d).format('DD/MM');
            });
```

I still would like to repeat weekly starting on Monday, but ignore Saturday and Sunday from the range.

Thanks

Comment: You could use `.tickValues([array])` and generate an array with Saturday and Sunday removed. Alternatively if spacing is irrelevant then you might be able to use `.tickFormat(function (d){...})` to selectively hide the weekends (i.e. return an empty string in the function).

Comment: @JSBob, I though about doing it, but I want the interval to be infinite, I don't want to define a start and end date, so defining the array using `.tickValues` wouldn't work. - I'm working with a draggable grid and users are able to drag to any point in time.

Comment: @Lucas Garcia Did you  find nay solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: No @Dev, I don't think there will be a simple way to do it any time soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 Non-Continuous Dates Domain Gives Gaps on X-Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129412/d3-non-continuous-dates-domain-gives-gaps-on-x-axis)