# Non continuous date domain using scaleTime()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Preface: I've gone through all other stackoverflow questions relating to this problem I could find, which are outdated or recommend using a ordinal scale instead. Including this one: [D3 Non-Continuous Dates Domain Gives Gaps on X-Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129412/d3-non-continuous-dates-domain-gives-gaps-on-x-axis)
which describes my problem as well.

Goal: I am trying to create a candlestick chart with zoom in/zoom out and panning. Currently the chart is working as intended, minus the x-axis (which contains dates/times of each candlestick).
I want the x axis to function like it does with scaleTime(), where it shows years/months, and when you zoom in it shows the date/time, depending on the time interval. I know timeScale() is continuous, but I need the functionality of the zooming in and out.

Problem: Gaps are included in the x-axis since when I set the domain for the x-scale and x-band, I am using the minimum and maximum dates in the dataset (named 'prices').

Code (d3js v7):

Works but x-scale is not dates, but decimal values from -1 to dates.length:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([-1, dates.length])
    .rangeRound([0, w]);
```

Works x-scale is dates, but includes gaps for weekends and holidays:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([xmin, xmax])
    .rangeRound([0, w]);
```

Doesn't work, x-scale is blank, coordinates are messed up:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(prices.map(r => r.t))
    .rangeRound([0, w]);
```

I calculate the x coordinates for my candle bodies for (map) and [xmin,xmax] as:

```
.attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(d.t) - xBand.bandwidth())
```

or for domain([-1, dates.length])

```
.attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i) - xBand.bandwidth())
```

xBand is declared as:

```
let xBand = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(d3.range(-1, dates.length))
    .range([0, w])
    .padding(0.2);
```

Another solution I can think of is to somehow convert the demical values from the domain in the first xScale example to function like the scaleTime() scale using tickFormat(), but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. I have already converted them from decimal to dates using .tickFormat(prices.map(d => new Date(d.t))); but don't know where to go from there.

Questions: Can you pass an array of values as the domain? Or is it just a min and max value, since domain is defined as boundaries within which your data lies?

Am I passing the array mapping correctly? Is this allowed?

Finally, how can I set my domain to the array of dates I have without including gaps on the chart?

Comment: What's wrong with *if today is a non trading day, take the price of the last trading day* ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie That is just filtering out data based on a precondition, which requires a set of predefined variables, which are weekends and holidays, for which I would need to have a complete list of the past years. While this could work for daily data, it would not work for a 1 minute chart. For this reason I need to only pass in dates for which data is available.